# Get one item from an array based on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with different values (in JSON structure), I need to get one item on the array based on another value.

This is what I did so far:

```
var orders= [{
    "id": 1,
    "order": "11"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "order": "22"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "order": "33"
  }];
var order = $.grep(orders, function (e) { return e.order === '22'; })[0];
var orderID = order ? order.id : 0;
```

Is this the simplest way to do it?

Comment: `var myOrder = orders.find(o => o === order)`

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need? ES6 introduces `find` for `var order = orders.find(e => e.order === order)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @Weedoze,Ryan, Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ES6, you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var orders= [{ id: 1, order: "11" }, { id: 2, order: "22" }, { id: 3, order: "33" }],
    order = orders.find(o => o.order === "22"),
    orderID = order ? order.id : 0;

console.log(orderID);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much simpler than the `grep` function, thank you!

Comment: If I need to get the `id` of the found `order` I need the second line of code? That can't be done on the `find` function?

Comment: `find` returns `undefined`, if no item is found. you need a check later and get the id, or a default value